# Created individual files/folders and immediately use their Ids? (Google Drive API)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, salesforce, visualforce

**SHORT VERSION OF QUESTION:**

Using Javascript, I'd like to create folders in a structure, confirming if any/all/none of the folders already exist.  So, given folder names "A", "B", "C", and "D", create "A", put it in root, then create "B", and put it inside "A", and so on. The issue is that no matter how I structure it, all folders are inserted asynchrously meaning they don't have their respective ParentIds and they all wind up in root.

**LONG VERSION WITH WIP:**

I'm trying to create three (or more) folders at once which will all be on the same path.

For example, if I want the file path to be State\City\Street. I start by having the folders in an array in their desired order (note that in my final project these will not be hardcoded, but dynamically named based on the user and salesforce record they are viewing).

```
const filePath = ["State", "City", "Street"];
```

I then passed it onto this method which is suppose to create these folders one at a time, using the prior folder's Id as it's parentId.

```
        function createFolder() {

            var parentFolderId = "root";

            for (let i = 0; i < filePath.length; i++) {

                    var folderMetadata = {
                        'name' : filePath[i],
                        'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                        'parents': [parentFolderId]
                    }
                    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                        resource: folderMetadata,
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        switch(response.status){
                            case 200:
                                var file = response.result;
                                parentFolderId = file.Id;
                                console.log(i + ' file.Id= ' + file.Id);
                                break;
                            default:
                                console.log('Error creating the folder, ' + response);
                                break;
                        }
                    });
             }
        }
```

However, all folders are created after the function finishes, before the "parentFolderId = file.Id;" line runs, so they are all put into root.

I realize that I could create all folders, query them, then rearrange them. However, the next part of my project is dynamically determining if any/all of these folders already exist, and the folder structure could vary a lot.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: the file.create method is singular it will only create one file at a time.

Comment: @ziganotschka - My exact question is "How do you created individual files/folders and immediately use their Ids with Google Drive API?".
Specifically, I want to create many folders all at once, each on being a child of the previous, so each child will need the previous folders Id, despite them all being created within the same method.

Comment: @DaImTo - Thanks, but I don't understand.  Do you mean that I need to change "gapi.client.drive.files.create" to "gapi.client.drive.file.create"? Because that resulted in an error:Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gapi.client.drive.file.create')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, With a little tweaking, @Alessandro's solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540389/create-a-tree-directory-structure-in-google-drive-with-javascript/68402143#68402143) worked for me:

- I reversed the order of the methods just for readability.
- I incorporated a FOR loop because my file structure will go many folders deep. The loops is through an array of strings containing the folder names in the file path.
- I noticed that (!parent) wasn't returning properly because it was "undefined", not "null". Also, expecting "null" when the existing folder wasn't found was vital, so I defaulted parentId to "root" since I know my first folder will always be at root
- variable newFolderId holds the value of the found/created folder, and is passed onto the parentId for the next iteration of the FOR loop
- Finally, I updated "'parent': parent" to be "'parents' : [parent]". That "s" and those brackets seem necessary, otherwise every created folder is placed at root.

```
        async function buildFilePath() {

            console.log("buildFilePath()");

            var parentId = "root";

            for (let i = 0; i < filePath.length; i++)  {
                var folderName = filePath[i];

                newFolderId = await getFolder(folderName, parentId);
                console.log(folderName + " id is " + newFolderId + ", parentId is " + parentId);
                if (newFolderId == null) {
                    newFolderId = await createFolder(folderName,parentId);
                    console.log ("created new folder " + folderName + " with Id " + parentId);
                } else {
                    // parentId = newParentId;
                    console.log (folderName + " already exist, move on to next.");
                }
                parentId = newFolderId;
            }
        }
        async function getFolder(name, parent) {

            const res = await gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'pageSize': 1,
                'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents)",
                'q': "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' \
                            and '" + parent + "' in parents \
                            and name = '" + name + "' \
                            and trashed = false"
            });
            return res.result.files.length > 0 ? res.result.files[0]['id'] : null;
        }
        async function createFolder(name, parent) {

            if (!parent) parent = 'root';

            var fileMetadata = {
                'name': name,
                'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'parents': [parent]
            };
            const res = await gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                'resource': fileMetadata,
                'fields': 'id'
            });
            return res.result['id'];
        }
```